# Why retransmision occured 16 seconds later?

Tags: tcp, socket-timeout-exception

I use jmeter to test a tomcat web application running behind f5's load balancer.
From the pcap file I captured in jmeter node I see that there is a duplicate ack and then
16 seconds later the client retransmit the packet and do nothing within 20 seconds.
[image: No packet sent in 20 seconds]

As tomcat's default socket timeout is set as 20 seconds the client received Http error.

My question is:
What could be the reason that make client's TCP stack retransmit after 16 seconds and later do nothing within 20 seconds? Is it too busy? Is there a way to find out the reason?

Comment: More likely the *client* retransmitted the request.

Comment: Do you mean client retransmitted the packets but the load balancer drop them and eventually the server timeout? From the pcap file it doesn't seem like that.